# Django(Oscar) - перестали отображаться опции(товаров) - в админке

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с данной проблемой совсем недавно(после переустановки проекта, целиком), в меню админки Oscar(DashBoard), есть меню которое отвечает за опции товара, раньше там отображался список из которого можно выбрать Option >Size, Option> Color

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь там пусто, а вот на страничке самого товара, эти опции отображаются без проблем.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Так же раньше можно было выбрать в выпадающем меню атрибутов, тип этого атрибута - Option;Text;Integer И тд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно понять где требуется что-то добавить либо изменить, я переустановил абсолютно чистую версию Django Oscar, и вот такая вот проблема возникла.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему переустановкой содержимого Python/lib site-packages , не знаю точно в чем была проблема, ибо пришлось все полностью удалять.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]